# Can this preg_replace_callback method be done in xPath or XQuery?

Tags: php, xslt, preg-replace, xquery

The script below takes the $myContent block and does the doReplace() function on the $myKeyword value. The problem I have is that it does not know if the replacement text is already inside a tag or not.

I need to modify the doReplace() function so that it does not touch any text inside of or as attributes of the named tags (h1, h2, h3, i, u, b, strong, em, img).

I think it would be better to convert this over to an xPath method and looking for suggestions on how it might be done with xPath. So the question is: "How would you convert this to xPath"?

Note: The count variable in the replace function is there because I'm only replacing on the first three appearances of the keyword. First time it appears it gets bolded, next time it gets italicized and the third time it appears, it gets underlined.

```
$myKeyword = "test keyword";

$myContent = "My content contains the "test keyword". 
Don't do the replace if the test keyword is inside:
h1, h2, h3, i, u, b, strong, em, tags. 
<h1>This test keyword would not be replaced</h1>";

$myContent = preg_replace_callback("/\b($mykeyword)\b/i","doReplace", $myContent);

function doReplace($matches)
{
    static $count = 0;
    switch($count++) {
    case 0: return ' <b>'.trim($matches[1]).'</b>';
    case 1: return ' <em>'.trim($matches[1]).'</em>';
    case 2: return ' <u>'.trim($matches[1]).'</u>';
    default: return $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't clear. Show us the source XML and show the wanted result. What is `$matches`?. Please, show us a real example. Format your code so that no horizontal scrolling is needed -- as it is now it is difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @Dimitre - I've reformatted the code. The source would be $myContent and would be loaded via loadHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in XPath 1.0 nor 2.0, because you need recursion to express this algorithm. You could use an extension function, of course.

This XQuery:

```
declare variable $match as xs:string external;
declare variable $replace as xs:string external;
declare variable $preserve as xs:string external;
declare variable $vPreserve := tokenize($preserve,',');
declare function local:copy-replace($element as element()) {   
   element {node-name($element)}
           {$element/@*,  
            for $child in $element/node()   
                return if ($child instance of element())   
                       then local:copy-replace($child)   
                       else if ($child instance of text() and
                                not(name($element)=$vPreserve))
                            then replace($child,$match,$replace)
                            else $child
           }
};   
local:copy-replace(/*)
```

With this input:

```
<html>
    <h1>This test keyword would not be replaced</h1>
    <p>This test keyword should be replaced</p>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <h1>This test keyword would not be replaced</h1>
    <p>This replaced should be replaced</p>
</html>
```

Also this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:param name="pMatch" select="'test keyword'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pReplace" select="'replaced'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pPreserve" select="'h1,h2,h3,i,u,b,strong,em'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(concat(',',$pPreserve,','),
                                     concat(',',name(..),','))">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="pString" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pString,$pMatch)">
                <xsl:value-of
                     select="concat(substring-before($pString,
                                                     $pMatch),
                                    $pReplace)"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                                    select="substring-after($pString,
                                                            $pMatch)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: Better XQuery.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. I've retagged with your suggestion.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks! Do I pass my content to copy-replace($myContent)? Where do I pass the keyword to the function? copy-replace($myContent, $myKeyword)?

Comment: @Scott B: You need to pass parameter to your XQuery/XSLT processor. That depends on your host language. If that is PHP, I don't think you have a native XQuery processor (You could use a .Net/Java bridge to use Saxon, Altova or XQSharp). So, you should use the XSLT solution, instead.

Comment: Thanks Alexandro. Wow, that's quite a lot to chew on. My original function was so simple.

Comment: @Scott B: That's because you need to deal with nested elements. The XSLT solutions is not so complex: an identity rule (copy input as is); a text nodes rule, test for parent element being in the preserve list, then output as is, otherwise call a recursive named template; a recursive named template outputs the replacement as long as there is a match in the remaining string.