# How to write result of xpath translation

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Once I've done the node conversion in the foreach, how do I get a copy of $myContent, complete with all replaced nodes?

echo $xPath does not work

```
$myContent ="<h1>This word should not be replaced: test</h1>. 
  But this one should be replaced: Test";

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($myContent);
$xPath = new DOMXPath(@$dom);
foreach($xPath->query("//text()[contains(.,'test') and not(ancestor::h1)]") as $node)
{
    $node->textContent = "<b>".trim($match[1])."</b>";   
}
```

Comment: You may also want to stop with the @ error suppression - it really affects performance for one thing and will make problems harder to trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here...

- `$node->textContent = "<b>".trim($match[1])."</b>";` should not work because you're trying to create an element (`<b>`) but stick it into a parent element's text content. Unless PHP DOMNode is smarter than the documentation says, it won't parse your `<b>` markup and create a new element. You need to do that with `createElement()` and `createTextNode()`.
- Modifying the textContent of each `$node` should modify the `$dom` document, but it will not affect `$myContent`. To get a string serialization of the modified DOM document, use $dom->[saveHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)().

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks. That helps greatly. Any idea how to remove '<html><body>' wrapper from the result of $dom->saveHTML()?

Comment: @Scott: you might try $dom.saveXML() (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) which shouldn't add that wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Lars. now I just need to figure out how to wrap the token value  in b tags and I'm near done with this.

Comment: *(hint)* PHP does not access objects with a dot

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks, I was able to replace that with ->

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks, I'll fix it in my answer too. I'm here in an XPath capacity, and am not a PHP programmer. :-)

Comment: @Scott, for that use createElement('b', $yourTokenValue). But you may need to split the text node $node into two, around the new `b` element.

Comment: @Scott: Everyone who uses something else than XSLT to solve such a task must be a masochist. Please, ask a question how to do this with XSLT and you'll get good answers.

Comment: @Dimitre: He did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077624/can-this-preg-replace-callback-method-be-done-in-xpath-or-xquery

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$node->nodeValue` instead of `$node->textContent`
Also, you can't use `'<b>'` in nodeValue. You must create DOMElement and append it to $node